# Storing single string into a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is in the last sentence, here's an brief introduction. I have searched different ways of putting one element in a set on the internet. For example,

```
set1 = {"String"}
```

or

```
set1 = set()
set1.add("String")
```

you may have known using the following way give a set of letters

```
set1 = set("String") 
#{'S','t','r','i','n','g'}
```

the solution would be that

```
set1 = set(["String"])
```

my question is: **What happens behind the scene? Why can this method solve the problem?**

Comment: Did you read `help(set)`? If not, why?

Comment: Thanks for your advice:) next time I will use help to check first

Answer (score 2):

In Python a string is a sequence type, whose elements are simply its individual characters. Since the `set()` constructor takes a sequence and converts its elements to its set items, passing a string to the `set()` constructor creates a set of the string's individual characters. If you want a set of strings instead, you then need to pass to the `set()` constructor a list of strings in order to avoid the string itself being treated as a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The `set` constructor either takes nothing or an iterable. Strings in python are iterables:

```
>>> [c for c in "string"]
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

By putting your string inside another iterable, e.g. a list - `["string"]`, `set` will construct a set containing the unique elements of the list.